# Sine function in Math Node in Blender

Tags: mathematics

Hey guys I'm new to Blender. I don't know about [Sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine) function in [`Math Node`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/math.html). Blender's official manual redirects me to the Wikipedia page but in there I don't understand the process. I want to know how to predict the output of the sine function and how it works in Blender.

Comment: Do you know sine from elsewhere?  The sine function is exactly like any other sine function: sine(theta) is the Y coordinate of a unit vector as it rotates about the origin by theta radians in an XY coordinate system, starting at 0 radians for a 1,0 +X vector.  So the sine of 0 is 0; the sine of pi/2 (90 degrees) is 1 (vector rotated 90 degrees is at 0,1); sine of pi/4 is 2^0.5/2.

Comment: maybe you have written your question a bit unfortunate...but as Nathan wrote and understood it - your questions sounds like you don't know sin function at all...and if so - than you should post your question in a math forum, not here

Comment: Thank you Chris and Nathan for your support.

Comment: I think the OP was just confused on why for example sine(90) would not return 1 as he might have expected. He probably expected the inputs to be degrees but didn't know that Blender's trigo functions use angles in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) instead of [degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle))

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie: that's why he should improve/edit his question to make it clear what exactly his problem is...it's pretty vague so...‍♂️

Comment: agreed. that's why i voted to close XD

Answer (score 1):

This plane is slightly wider than 2pi, slightly deeper than 2. It's mapped in its Object coordinates. Its object-origin is at its centre.

[image]

The *Math > Sine* node returns the sine of its input, where the input is in radians.

Comment: What is the domain before it repeats? Slightly wider than 4pi??

Comment: @Richard ... Yikes! I've got the scale wrong by 2! The period should be 2pi, Correcting it now...

Comment: Yeah, just tested that

Comment: @Richard Thanks.... done now :)

Answer (score 1):

Sine outputs a number from -1 to 1. You can use the `Map Range` node afterwards to convert it to any range you want.

To ensure your animation loops seamlessly, add a `Map Range` node before the sine that outputs 0 to 2*pi (you can actually type pi in the max value box and it will accept it).

Comment: Fun fact for geeks... You can also type `tau` for 2pi